# Searching for a string within an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Below I am trying to create a method which searches through an array for a certain string and returns the position of it, if not there then -1 should be the number returned. Below I search for a word using the method and it returns -1 even though the word is within the array. Why is this?

```
    String answer = "";

    System.out.println("Enter word to search within array");
    answer = in.next();


       public static int search(String[] theWords, String answer) {
         int a = -1;
         for(int i = 0; i < theWords.length; i++) {
             if (answer.equals(theWords[i])){
                 a = i;
                 break;
             }
         } 
         return a;
     }
```

Comment: You can directly return `a` from the `if` condition itself.

Comment: For one thing: `Arrays.asList(theWords).indexOf(answer)` is your friend. For another, you should show a complete example of when this fails. It looks fine to me (not the code I'd write, but it should work) - so you should help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: my guess would be the sting is probably `answer` and `theWords[i]` are different case. did you try `answer.equalsIgnorecase(theWords[i])` ??

Comment: that code works for me. My guess is that answer is not in thewords.

Comment: Please give your input. Your method should work.

Comment: is it going to be exactly same word or is it if an entry includes that word. Also, if there is more than one element in array that is equal to your word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally make a copy of the array since sorting might be unwanted for consumers of the method

```
public static int Search(String[] thewords, String answer) {  
     if(thewords == null) {  
        throw new NullPointerException();  
     }  
     String[] copy = new String[thewords.length];  
     System.arraycopy(thewords,0,copy,0,copy.length);  
     Arrays.sort(thewords);    
     return Arrays.binarySearch(thewords, answer);  
}
```

Note: It returns `-pos` and not `-1`

If you need `-1`:

```
public static int Search(String[] thewords, String answer) {  
     if(thewords == null) {  
        throw new NullPointerException();  
     }  
     String[] copy = new String[thewords.length];  
     System.arraycopy(thewords,0,copy,0,copy.length);  
     Arrays.sort(thewords);  
     int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(thewords, answer);  
     return idx < 0? -1:idx;  
}
```

**Concerning your code:** I believe the problem would be related to casing or spacing:
Replace with something like: `if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(theWords[i].trim())){`

For large arrays go with binary search.

Comment: What if the array is not sorted?

Comment: Now the solution is correct, but inefficient. Sorting would take O(n lg n) time and you can just iterate the array with a complexity of O(n).

Comment: Calling your implementation would have the inexpeted side effect of sorting the array (bad). Better make a copy if you must persist with binarySearch

Comment: @Bohemian:I don't persist with binary. I just showed the OP a valid alternative. I agree with your comment about the side-effect of copy and updated answer.

Comment: @MAV:I mention to use binary search for large data set in the answer

Comment: @Cratylus Doesn't matter how big the data set is. The fact that you sort the array and THEN use a binary search make the running time worse than just iterating through the array. Now that you also copy the array, you add another run through of the array. If the strings was maintained in a sorted datastructure your search makes sense. In this case it does not.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything wrong with the code, but I would recommend eliminating the local variable that holds the return value:

```
 public static int Search(String[] thewords, String answer) {
     for (int i = 0; i < thewords.length; i++) {
         if (answer.equals(thewords[i])){
             return i;
         }
     } 
     return -1;
 }
```

With this simplified logic, there's little or no chance of there being a bug in this code.

---

I assume this is course work, and you are not allowed to use library methods. If you were allowed, your method could be a single line:

```
return Arrays.asList(theWords).indexOf(answer);
```